# Optimization of a substring query with charindex to trim the left part of a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to get a substring of xyzdf/1234  resulting in 1234 (i.e. trimming the left part of the slash / ) . I have used

```
substring('xyzdf/1234',charindex('/','xyzdf/1234')+1,len('xyzdf/1234')-charindex('/','xyzdf/1234'))
```

which works but it is repetitive...

then I have used this way:

`stuff('xyzdf/1234',1,charindex('/','xyzdf/1234'),'')` and it works too and it is more compact, but still repeats the same argument twice 'xyzdf/1234'.

I wonder what would be the faster way to trim the left part. I will need to clean data in one column for million records. Not sure if the `stuff` command is faster enough. (Mind you it is a bulk operation). Thanks!

Comment: It is unclear what your question is.  You have offered two valid ways to do what you want to do.

Comment: Just asking about the  clauses that offer better performance in speed to update the column. It seems it does not matter if I use stuff or substring.Tthe difference of speed between both cases is (?) negligible when it comes to update many records.

Comment: @graphene less code is better, fewer computations is better too. This not a part of `WHERE` clause or `JOIN` predicate. It is very easy to test it yourself is there any difference at all. And such an optimization is barely worth time wasted.

Answer (score 2):

You could select the string from a VALUES.
That way you can repeat the value without double hardcoding it.
Then get the right part with the number from it.

F.e. using RIGHT, CHARINDEX, REVERSE and VALUES:

```
select right(val, charindex('/',reverse(val))-1) as nr
from (values ('xyzdf/1234')) q(val);
```

Or use SUBSTRING, CHARINDEX, LEN and VALUES:

```
select substring(val,charindex('/',val)+1,len(val)) as nr
from (values ('xyzdf/1234')) q(val);
```

Or abuse [PARSENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql):

```
select parsename(replace('xyzdf/1234','/','.'),1) as nr;
```

Or use variables:

```
declare @value varchar(30) = 'xyzdf/1234';
declare @nr int = right(@value, charindex('/',reverse(@value))-1);
select @nr as nr;
```

But if the intention is to update a column so that only the number remains? 
Then using the SUBSTRING method is probably still the safest.
Because it would keep those without `/` untouched, and without crashing on an `Invalid length parameter passed` error.

Example:

```
declare @Table table (id int identity(1,1) primary key, col1 varchar(30));

insert into @Table (col1) values 
('xyzdf/1234'),
('12345');

update @Table 
set col1 = substring(col1,charindex('/',col1)+1,len(col1))
where col1 like '%/[0-9]%';

select * from @Table;
```